# How to use wildcards in CssSelector when finding an element through Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriver

I have an issue where the CssSelector I am using has a GUID in it that changes every time and therefore the tests will only ever pass once. Is there a wildcard I can use in the CssSelector that will help me get round this? Consider the following code...

```
IWebElement PersonalPhone = Driver.driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("# Grid365e0689-dccb-695f-97af-dc29187d4e1d-id-cell-0-7 > a"));
PersonalPhone.Click();
```

I would like the above code to locate the element via the CssSelector using a wildcard so that I can remove the GUID part of the selector and only find the element based on the last part 'id-cell-0-7' and then click on the element.

I am using Selenium WebDriver(Chrome) written in C#

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use partial `id` with contains `*=`

```
IWebElement PersonalPhone = Driver.driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[id*='id-cell-0-7'] > a"));
```

Or end with `$=`

```
IWebElement PersonalPhone = Driver.driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[id$='id-cell-0-7'] > a"));
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of the `id` attribute looks dynamic to me so as an alternative you can use the following [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors):

```
IWebElement PersonalPhone = Driver.driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[id^='Grid'][id*='-id-cell-'] > a"));
PersonalPhone.Click();
```

Optimizing the lines of code in a single line:

```
Driver.driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[id^='Grid'][id*='-id-cell-'] > a")).Click();
```

---

### Explanation

The `id` attribute:

- Always start with **`Grid`** followed by the dynamic value, so you can use **`^`** to indicate *starts-with*
- Always contain **`-id-cell-`** at the rear end, so you can use `*` to indicate *contains*

---

However, as the desired element is a dynamic element so to invoke `click()` on the element you may have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `ElementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("[id^='Grid'][id*='-id-cell-'] > a"))).Click();
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'Grid') and contains(@id, '-id-cell-')]/a"))).Click();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to give you this news, but xpath 1.0 its still used in most drivers... quite:

> As other answers have noted, XPath 1.0 does not support regular
>   expressions.

Suggested way is to use the parent elements to locate the element you wish to click.

or..
if the `grid-xxx--xxx--` id keyword is constant you can do something like

Xpath: `//*[starts-with(@id, 'Grid')]/a` - id starts with Grid

CSS: `input[id^='Grid'] > a` - id starts with Grid

Change the *input* to the actual web element.

Comment: What about instead of grid we have something like <macroponent-a1f45e123ad41...  The part after the "-" could be anything so we want to find a match on macroponent* ?